# CakePHP 3.x dynamic finder method

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have this problem with a CakePHP 3 application
I am trying to get a category by it's slug and all related articles belonging to that category.
I am using dynamic finder method findBySlug in the Controller but it throws an error in the view.

Here is my code:

```
public function view($slug = null)
{
    if (!$slug) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid category slug'));
    }

    $category = $this->Categories->findBySlug($slug, [
        'contain' => [
            'Articles'
        ]
    ]);

    $this->set(compact('category'));
}
```

and the view:

```
<div class="categories view">

<h2><?= h($category->name); ?></h2>

<?php foreach ($category->articles as $article): ?>
    <?php echo $article->title; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Can anyone please provide or point me to a solution ?

Thank you in advance

And this is the debug I am getting in the controller:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Category) {

'new' => false,
'accessible' => [
    'name' => true,
    'slug' => true,
    'articles' => true
],
'properties' => [
    'id' => (int) 2,
    'name' => 'International',
    'slug' => 'international.html'
],
'dirty' => [],
'original' => [],
'virtual' => [],
'errors' => [],
'repository' => 'Categories'
```

}

and here are my models:

class CategoriesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

```
    $this->displayField('name');

    $this->hasMany('Articles', [
        'className' => 'Articles',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'conditions' => [
            'published' => 1
        ],
        'dependent' => true
    ]);
}
```

}

class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

```
    $this->belongsTo('Users');

    $this->belongsTo('Categories', [
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id'
    ]);
}
```

}

Comment: What error does it throw? Could you post it?

Comment: Notice (8): Undefined property: Cake\ORM\Query::$name [APP/Template/Categories/view.ctp, line 3]

Comment: Notice (8): Undefined property: Cake\ORM\Query::$articles [APP/Template/Categories/view.ctp, line 5]

Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/Template/Categories/view.ctp, line 5]

Comment: Well.. it looks like what you are returning cannot be pulled like that ($category->name). In your finder try to add `->first();` and see if that helps... so basically `])->first();`

Comment: if it doesn't work,  leave `->first()` in place and add `debug($category)` right after it and post the content debug will print to you screen, here.

Comment: Hi Andre, thank you for your response.
I tried what you said and it only fetches the category name this time
but no related articles> 
This time the error is: 
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/Template/Categories/view.ctp, line 5]
and the debug message is: 
object(App\Model\Entity\Category) {

 'new' => false,
 'accessible' => [
  '*' => true
 ],
 'properties' => [
  'id' => (int) 2,
  'name' => 'International',
  'slug' => 'international.html'
 ],
 'dirty' => [],
 'original' => [],
 'virtual' => [],
 'errors' => [],
 'repository' => 'Categories'

}

Comment: Alot of things can be happening. For example if the categories dont have any articles it will not return any. Do the `debug($category)` in your controller and add the result of it back in your question so it is easy to read. I should be able to see what is going on based on that.

Comment: I posted the debug as well.
The categories do have articles in them :)

Comment: Ok... it looks like your table relation might not be setup correctly. Look into your `src/Model/Table` classes of `CategoriesTable.php` and `ArticlesTable.php` and see if your relation are good there. You can also post the initialize method of each on your question and I will take a look.

Comment: Also, although what you are doing is correct and I dont see anything wrong with it.. I would do something like this as the finder you are using is a little bit more "expensive" :  `$category = $this->Categories->find()->where(['slug' => $slug])->contain(['Articles'])->first();`

Answer (score 0):

the `find()` method will always return a `Query` object. You need to fetch at least one result before trying to get properties from it:

```
$thisIsAQuery = $this->Categories->findBySlug($slug)->contain(['Articles'])
// I can now fetch the category
$category = $thisIsAQuery->first();


// And now I can get the category name
echo $category->name
```

Comment: And on top of that, dynamic finders do not (yet?) support options, requiring to for example use `Query::contain()` instead.