# cakephp 3.0 i can't get on my template the data stored, after a set() on my controller

Tags: cakephp-3.0

i've completily rebuild my question for clarity.

i'm getting an "undefined property error" on my view when i try to get 
the data stored

This is what i have in my controller:

```
    $this->set('magazines', $this->Issues->Magazines->find()
      ->select(['id', 'magazine_name'])
      ->where(['id' => $magazineId]));
```

and this is what i coded on the template:

```
echo $magazines->magazine_name;
```

the result is:
    Notice (8): Undefined property: Cake\ORM\Query::$magazine_name           [APP/Template/Issues/add.ctp, line 15]

what i want to obtain is to echo the manazine_name property and them store 
the id property on a variable

```
$id = $magazines->id;
```

thanks in advance

**ANSWER**
[CakePHP 3.x dynamic finder method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519870/cakephp-3-x-dynamic-finder-method)

Comment: what are you trying to do? what are you expecting?

Comment: That's not an array, that's a JSON encoding of an entity object. Look at the hydrate(false) method to have the find return arrays instead of entities.

Comment: Echoing the magazine name isn't really what you want to do here, is it? You are still not understanding what the query is returning. In your original question, you thought it was returning an array of values, now you think it's returning a single entity. What you are actually getting is a collection of entities. Please look at the documentation again, in particular the hydrate function that I mentioned earlier as well as toArray, to get a better grasp of what data the various query types can return and how they relate to each other.

Comment: thanks Greg. Yes, i want to echo the magazine name but i just obtain an undefined property

Comment: In your add.ctp view, open your DebugKit toolbar, open Variables, and see what your 'magazines' variable looks like.  Maybe there's a typo in magazine_name (similar to the typo in your question, 'manazine_name')?  If you set it as you show in your controller, you'll just have the query, so you might want to add the ->toArray() method to the query so you can view the actual values in your add template.